# iOS: Is there any solution yet for Core Animation problems on 64-bit?

Tags: ios, 64-bit, cabasicanimation

We recently converted our app to full 64-bit compatibility, and now CABasicAnimations across the entire app are failing on 64-bit devices (animations that have been working for years on all devices). A question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789877/cabasicanimation-doesnt-work-on-64-bit-iphone-5s-device), but received no response. What is the current knowledge surrounding this issue? I can't find much written about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but it could be related.

`UIView` animations that use `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` no longer interrupt existing animations as of iOS 8. Cancelling animations now has to be done explicitly with `removeAnimationForKey`.

Maybe if you described what "failing" means in more detail and provided a short code snippet that demonstrates the erroneous behaviour, there may be different insight into a solution.

Comment: The behavior is extremely unpredictable, and the animations basically flicker and freak out on screen. The code runs through a pretty complex animation framework so I can't really post individual samples, but I'll look into the above. I'll note, though, that this is exclusive to 64 bit devices, and only started happening once arm64 was added to valid archs, so I don't think the above is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark: a common cause of problems when going from 32 to 64 bits is related to the [size of data types such as floats, integers, longs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/Major64-BitChanges/Major64-BitChanges.html), etc.

Speaking of animations, a likely culprit are floating point values. If you have used `float`s in your code, then maybe you are out of luck. Indeed, the framework expects `CGFloat` to represent floating point numbers, so there will be this implicit cast done by the compiler. Ooh the other hand, `float` have not changed their size, while `CGFloat` have (from 32 to 64 bits). This could explain the widespread problems you are having.